# Uploading a file to django model with a form - is_valid() fails

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to upload a file to a django model with a form, however it fails when it reaches `form.is_valid()`.

I'm adding the form to a Twitter Bootstrap modal, which I guess could be causing issues?

When I print `form.errors`, I get a message saying that the form is required. I'm obviously adding a text file to the form before submission, so I'm not sure what the issue could be.

`views.py` - Successfully gets past `request.method == 'POST'`. Fails at `form.is_valid()`.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ConfigurationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    print("ERROR " + str(form.errors))
    if form.is_valid():
         print("Success")
    elif not form.is_valid():
        print("Failed")
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from .models import NetworkApplications


class ConfigurationForm(forms.Form):
    config_file = forms.FileField(label="Select a file")

    class Meta:
        model = NetworkApplications
```

In my template:

```
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    {{form.config_file}}
</form>
```

`request.FILES` seems to be empty.

`form.errors` returns this:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>config_file<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is
required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

Footer:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="destroyModal('newApplicationModal');">Close</button>
    <button type="button" id="newNetworkModalSave" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addNewApplication();" data-dismiss="modal" >Save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: When the form is displayed, does it have a file upload field?

Comment: Where is the submit button ?...

Comment: Since it's a bootstrap modal, it's further down in the 'modal-footer' div. Edited the post.

Comment: image should pass in the keyname of `{'config_file': img_object}`